# how to return json in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have code.php and this file calculate quantity and price i want to return result thtat in json to index.php through ajax

code.php

```
$query = 'select * from products where sku='."'$sku'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$qty = $_GET['qty'];

$price_egp=number_format((float)($product['price1']*12.5), 3, '.', '');
$arr = array ('price'=>"$price",'qty'=>"$qty");

echo  json_encode($arr);
```

result  is

```
{"price":"40.9504305591","qty":"50"}
```

i want to return value in code.php in index.php

index.php

```
 function updateItems(ID,price){
        var qty=    document.getElementById( ID).value;
        //$('#'+target).html(price*qty);
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
       else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {


          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
               //here i want to return response(#qty).html();/*i don't know how rturn data from json here inside html */(#price).html();
            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("GET","code.php?op=updateItems&qty="+qty+"&price="+price+"&id="+itemIndex+"&sku="+ID,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send()


    }
enter code here
```

html code

Comment: i update it i didn't need query but i want to return json value to each div in index.php @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
     document.getElementById('qty').innerHTML = parseInt(json.qty);
     document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = parseFloat(json.price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` in the callback function

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var price = parseFloat(result.price);
    var qty = parseInt(result.qty, 10);
    // Do what you want with price and qty
};
```